# Whose offensive actions?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Iran has made a dramatic shift in how it confronts the United States,
>   abandoning a policy of restraint in recent weeks for a series of
>   **offensive actions** aimed at pushing the White House to rethink its
>   efforts at isolating Tehran, say diplomats and analysts.

I don't understand it was whose offensive actions.
I struggle 2 meanings.

> Iran ... abandoning restraint and adopted offensive actions.

or

> Iran ...
>   abandoning restraint because of the U.S.'s offensive actions.

Edit: After Cardinal's comment, I know the meaning.
I should ask what does "abandon A for B" mean.

> abandon A and adopt B

or

> abandon A because B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The participle clause is basically means to abandon something for something else. That's very close in meaning to "to leave something/someone for something\someone else".

Since you said you searched the internet, I did myself and this result popped up:

> "Reasons to Abandon Windows For Linux"

or

> "He abandoned the city for the sake of fame and adventure."

As you said, the idiomatic constructions are difficult to master for learners like us, but, here, you can break down the sentence word by word. As you guessed, the key word here is for.

**For** can be used to form many different prepositional phrases. Here it kind of means to exchange something for another thing.

Comment: PS: How did you find out these 2 examples? I searched "abandon for" and "abandon something for something". First 3 pages are all about "abandon" in all kind of dictionaries.